# CREATE FILE error (access is denied) connecting to SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I just started learning C#.  I installed VS 2013 Ultimate Update 1 and SQL Server 2012.

This are the steps I do:

1. Add a New Item (Service-Based) to a new console application project.
2. I double-click the newly created Database.mdf in Solution Explorer.
3. A Server Explorer Pane opens up... I then right-click "Tables", then click "Add New Table".

I get an hour glass for about a half a minute or so (with Visual Studio not responding).  Then, the whole Visual Studio app exits memory and restarts completely... taking me back to the Start Page.

I tried the same thing on a completely different Win7 PC. As soon as I double-click on a newly created Database.mdf in Solution Explorer, instead of getting an hour glass, I immediately got a

> CREATE FILE error (access is denied) while accessing d:\multimedia
>   files\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Day6\Day6\Database.mdf. 
>   User does not have permission to alter database
>   DD11DAA3-0B7F-4949-BCBB-E.....  ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

I have full/real administrator on both my PC's with UAC turned completely off.

So, why cant VS2013 access SQL Server Express 2012 properly on two completely separate PC configurations?  It really gives the impression that VS2013 is a clunky piece of junk.  Applying "Update 1" didn't help any.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me to get at least one PC with VS2013 to work correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a question, I noticed your drive is D:, which is usually CD drive.  Is that true in your case?  Or do you actually have a D: drive that you write to and read from with your program?

Comment: The reason I'm asking about whether drive D: is a CD drive, or not, is because Visual Studio can't create a table on a CD-ROM, unless it's an R/W CD-ROM.  That's why I was curious what type of drive it is.

Comment: Since you have installed Sql Server 2012 express edition on your machine, are you able to open up Management Console and connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a permission related issue with the database than with VS.  Quick way would to be enable mix mode. You can set it under properties -> Security -> SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode. Also check your connection string.